# Move uib Modal Content out of the modal content to top of page

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have some content in uib modal window. I want that conent to be moved to top of the html (fixed to the top of the html).

I tried setting

```
position: fixed;
top: 0
```

Its going to the top. But its still staying in the Modal Content(not to the top of the webpage)

[image]

[image]

How can i pull this out of the div and stick to the top of my webpage?

fiddle Here: https://jsfiddle.net/Mahesh434/6ktc4g8j/

Comment: try placing it outside the modal

Comment: that won't help.. that div should be in the modal.. But when i do some action (like scrolling) i need to move that to top of page.

Comment: the problem is the transform: translate(0,0) css property inside the modal-dialog. It is a kind of bug. With the transform: translate(0,0) property child elements with position: fixed are relative to the parent instead of the viewport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this using the below approach, hope this will help for someone.

adding css:

```
.modal-dialog {
  transform: none;
}
```

**Note:** But not sure what is the impact of adding this line;

In my case the model is working as expected without any issues.